# Netbeans: Change main-class for JAR generation while excluding original main-class

Tags: java, netbeans, build.xml

I'm writing a Java library in Netbeans 7 which contains a Demo.java main class which gets executed when the project runs. Now I added a Cli.java which is a main class, too. Now I would like to create a JAR file (which is no problem so far). That file should NOT contain the Demo.java but instead use the Cli.java as THE main class.

When I add "Main-Class: packagename.Cli" to the manifest.mf and build the project, the "Main-Class" gets overwritten with "packagename.Demo" although I excluded that class from within the project properties.

So I assume this only works when changing the build.xml (which would even be better as the file is in the version control system). But I haven't found out how to that. Can somebody guide me to a simple explanation or even provide some lines of XML to accomplish that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work so far:

```
<!--  Sets the Cli as new main class  -->
<manifest file="build/MANIFEST.MF">
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="packagename.Cli" />
</manifest>

<!--  exludes the demo for the jar creation  -->
<property name="excludes" value="**/packagename/of/demo/**"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project in the *Projects* panel. In *Run*, change the *Main Class* (there is a *Browse...* button to ease your pain). Save your changes and *Clean and build* it. That should do.

Comment: Hi. I do not want to change the main class for the run, but only for the JAR file.

Comment: No answer for that but run file instead of project.

Comment: Then I guess you have no options left.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the main class then make a new java class wich
will be the main class, once you build your program. your like
WTH??!! the jar file wont open!!! well extract the jar file and open 
META -INF (idk if i spelled it correct).  and open the only file with
Windows = NotePad
Mac = textEdit
change main class: DEAFULTNAME.PROJECTNAME to main class:thenameyouput.projectname

and itl work!    NO EXTRA CODE NEEDED